# How to check my if connection through a comport to a device is connected with JavaScript

Tags: com, connection

First, I'm very new to JavaScript. I have written a few working scripts that will read and write through a UART, then capture a part of the returned string and use it. I also have written a lot of code in a language called EZ Script that is designed by a company called Synthiam. They say EZ Script is very like JS. I'm in the process of converting some of my EZ Scripts into JS because JS runs much faster. I also have been wanting to learn JS.

I currently have a computer that runs the control software called ARC by Synthiam (capable of using JavaScript). The Computer is attached to an Arduino like device called an EZB that controls devices like servos and other things. The computer and the EZB are attached and sending data through USB cable and a COM port.

I'm trying to write a JavaScript that includes a command that checks if the two are currently connected through the COM port and active.

I've searched and tried many different JS commands but haven't been able to get anything to work.

In EZ Script I could do that using their IsConnected() command. I might add that ARC (the control software) allows many devices like the EZB or Arduino to be connected to it. Each has it's own board index.

**The command looks like this in EZ Script:**
IsConnected( boardIndex )
*Returns TRUE or FALSE if the specified EZ-B board index is connected
*Example: $status = IsConnected(0)

Is there a similar way to do this with Javascript? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved.

I contacted Synthiam's customer support and asked them what Javascript command I would use in ARC to check my connection to the computer. They must have some background scripting for this in their robot control software. They answered back to use the `EZB.isConnected` command. Like this:

```js
if (EZB.isConnected(0)) {
  print("EZB 0 is connected");
}
```

I did and it worked.